# Is my cat having trouble waking, seizures, or something else?

Tags: cats, behavior, health

Almost exactly a month ago, my cat Dylan (female, 5 years) was sleeping on a chair when she fell out of it, scrambled about with her belly low to the floor and her pupils widely dilated, head turning panicked from side to side for about a minute, then drooled briefly, and then seemed fine. I thought poisoning, because her sister ate a poisoned mouse long ago and acted similarly. But Dylan stopped after a minute and was normal again. I took her to the vet immediately nonetheless, but they found nothing, other than her heart had a slightly odd sound. She was perfectly fine until a moment ago today, when she suddenly seemed to get startled and then, once again, walked around close to the ground, wide pupils scanning the room from side to side with little or no reaction to others, and when she calmed down, she drooled briefly.

She seems fine now. I have checked and it looks nothing like epilepsy or any other seizure I could find video of. It looks like she woke very roughly from a bad dream and had trouble telling what was going on. But it still scares the **** out of me. Does anyone know what it might be?

Comment: You need to take her to another vet and get another opinion.

Comment: That is definitely the plan, but if the next veet has as little idea as this one I would like to know what to ask about. I have grown a bit skeptical of the skills of vets in my area...

Comment: Seizures can manifest in various different ways. In pets we often only recognize the "laying on the ground and twitching uncontrollably", but in humans we can also recognize a form of seizure where the person seems to check out from reality for a short while. They may almost act as if concious, but not react to their environment in any way that makes sense, and then suddenly they regain conciousness without remembering what they did during the seizure. In any case, if your cat has such an episode again, you should record a video of the whole thing to show your vet.

Comment: One of my cats sometimes rolls over in his sleep and falls off his tree, and he shows the same alarm when he hits the ground. Are you sure it’s a seizure, rather than just clumsiness?

Comment: StephenS I have considered that. She fell from a chair the first time, possibly because she rolled over. The second time I only saw her suddenlly shoot up and then crawlon the ground as if terrified. I am hoping it is just this odd behavior, because the vet had no better answers...